# How to open socket for sending data only in linux

Tags: linux, sockets

How can I open a socket for either sending data or for receiving data?
If you want to use socket for sending data, that  socket will not receive any data.

Is there any socket option is available for that?

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials on how to create and using sockets on the Internet, in all kind of languages. Use Google search. As for making a socket uni-directional (in C or C++) see Martijns answer.

Answer (score 3):

If both the sender and receiver processes are on the same machine, you can use a `pipe` instead of a socket, see the `pipe(2)` manual page for how it works.

If this is for communication over the network, you can just use a socket and not send data. If you want to make sure, you can use `shutdown(fd, SHUT_RD)` to close the writing part of your socket.

Comment: Although in this case use `SHUT_RD` as the OP only wants to send and not receive.

Comment: Ahem. Oops. Fixed. (time for coffee :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But I am using SOCK_DGRAM packets while opening socket .When i use shutdown() call ,it raises an error "Transport endpoint is not connected".And My communication is over network.please explain the solution .Thanks in Advance.

Comment: In that case, just don't call the sending (or receiving) calls on the socket file handles :)

Answer (score 1):

Use unix domain socket, and don't bind it:

```
fd = socket(PF_LOCAL, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
```

Then you can send by using a socket, but no-one is able to send data to the socket.
Even the receiver is not able to respond.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for communication over the network and you want to make sure that this will be a write only socket, you can use shutdown(fd, SHUT_RD) to close the writing part of your socket.
If this is a SOCK_DGRAM - a UDP socket, use connect() to connect to the remote peer and then call shutdown(). A shutdown() shuts down a connected socket.